# Electron best way for multiple windows

Tags: electron

What is the proper way to open multiple BrowserWindows? I do it like this and works fine so far. Is better to make an array of win?

```
let win;

function createWindow () {
  for (i=0; i<loadNotes.notes.length; i++){
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    'x': loadNotes.notes[i].pos.x,
    'y': loadNotes.notes[i].pos.y,
    'width': loadNotes.notes[i].pos.width,
    'height': loadNotes.notes[i].pos.height,
    'frame': false});

  win.setMenu(null);
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html?${loadNotes.notes[i].name}`);
  //win.webContents.openDevTools()
  }
  win.on('close', () => {

  })

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It depends on if you want to use the instance methods of `win` or not. If not you can leave your code as it is.
Just one suggestion, it is recommended that for best user experience you show your windows gracefully

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    ...., 
    show: false})
...
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html?${loadNotes.notes[i].name}`)
win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  win.show()
})
```

Comment: Hey, what does the graceful version do over the original?

Comment: It ensures that the window is only shown once the document is loaded, preventing the initial white flash: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#showing-the-window-gracefully

Answer (score 7):

For creating a multi window application in electron is easy. Here a nodejs module which help you to create a multi window app easily.

you can install this module by just executing the following command

`npm install --save electron-window-manager`

Then, inside the application main.js (or whatever you've chosen for your application), require the module, like this:

`var windowManager = require('electron-window-manager');`

**On the Main process you can use it like this:**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const windowManager = require('electron-window-manager');

// When the application is ready
app.on('ready', function(){
    windowManager.init( ... );
    // Open a window
    windowManager.open('home', 'Welcome ...', '/home.html');
});
```

**And in the Renderer process (inside the created window), you can use it like this:**

```
    var remote = require('remote');
    var windowManager = remote.require('electron-window-manager');

    // Create a new window
    var win2 = windowManager.createNew('win2', 'Windows #2');
    win2.loadURL('/win2.html');
    win2.onReady( ... );
    win2.open();
```

Please go ahead and check out the module code and see for yourself how it all works, there's no magic involved, but it's consistent and easy to read. Just have a look at the code and you are good to go.

here is a complete guide about this module i hope it will help

https://github.com/TamkeenLMS/electron-window-manager